# Function templates in C++ with Armadillo

Tags: c++, function, templates, armadillo

I am writing some function templates using armadillo linear algebra library, but it encounters some errors. I am still learning C++ and its aspects, so will be very much thankful for any possible solutions. Most of my functions are like the following,

```
template<typename T1>
void some_function(const Mat<T1> & p)
{
    unsigned int n = p.n_rows;
    // do some stuffs...
    // ....
}
```

My main function contains:

```
Mat<double> A = ones<Mat<double>>(4,4);
int a(2);
some_function(A);  // runs perfectly
some_function(a*A); // compilation error as follows

test_function.hpp:35:8: note: template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:22:17: note: ‘arma::enable_if2<true, const arma::eOp<arma::Mat<double>, arma::eop_scalar_times> >::result {aka const arma::eOp<arma::Mat<double>, arma::eop_scalar_times>}’ is not derived from ‘const arma::Mat<eT>’
some_function(a*A);
```

If I change the function as follows:

```
template<typename T1>
void some_function(const T1 & p)
{
    unsigned int n = p.n_rows;
    // do some stuffs...
    // ....
}
```

Then it gives the compilation error as follows:

```
test_function.hpp: In instantiation of ‘bool some_function(const T1&) [with T1 = arma::eOp<arma::Mat<double>, arma::eop_scalar_times>]’:
test.cpp:22:17:   required from here
test_function.hpp:37:26: error: ‘const class arma::eOp<arma::Mat<double>, arma::eop_scalar_times>’ has no member named ‘n_rows’
 unsigned int n = p.n_rows;
```

But the non-template functions work perfectly, like

```
void some_function(const Mat<double> & p)
{
    unsigned int n = p.n_rows();
    // do some stuffs...
    // ....
}
```

Any solutions??

Comment: It seems that `operator *(double, Mat<double>)` return a Lazy evaluation and not directly a `Mat<double>`...

Comment: The error is so clear. Template can be `int`. Does `int` has a member `n_rows()`?

Comment: @manetsus No. `int` do not have `n_rows`, but `Mat<T1>` has. In the second case, since I am only passing `Mat` class (or `int*Mat<>` ...), I think, only that version of the function will be instantiated.

@Jarod42 Yes, that may be the problem.

Comment: That means you want to tell that your first (among five in the question) code block is getting error, right?

Comment: From doc, there is constructor from `Mat<double>(arma::eOp<..>)` but can't find a way to force arma::eOp to *"decay"* to `Mat<..>`. and row_count getter has an other name: `get_n_rows()`...

Comment: @manetsus Yes. Both first and third block returns error...

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks, but other member functions of Mat class also not working. May be I should only use non-member functions, or overload user defined functions by hand.

Comment: @TitasChanda: I post an answer which may work. But I expect the library provided a proper way to handle that.

Comment: @Jarod42 - indeed the library does provide a proper way to handle that: the [.eval()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#eval_member) member function. For example: `my_function( (a*A).eval() )`

Comment: @TitasChanda - `n_rows()` doesn't exist. Instead, there is a read-only variable called [n_rows](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#attributes) (ie. without the `()` brackets). Use it like this: `unsigned int n = p.n_rows`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that with those helpers:

```
template <typename T>
const Mat<T>& as_Mat(const Mat<T>& m) {return m;}

template<typename T1, typename eop_type>
Mat<typename T1::elem_type> as_Mat(const eOp<T1, eop_type>& X)
{
    return {X};
}
```

You may write:

```
template<typename T>
void some_function(const T & p)
{
    const auto& mat = as_mat(p);
    unsigned int n = mat.n_rows();
    // do some stuffs...
    // ....
}
```

Comment: By the way, is there any significance to use initializer list in the second case? Happy to learn.. @Jarod42

Comment: I prefer to write `{X}` over verbose `Mat<typename T1::elem_type>(X)` or too implicit `X`.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [.eval()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#eval_member) member function to forcefully convert an Armadillo expression into a matrix.

You can then use the result of `.eval()` as the input to a function. For example:

```
mat A(10,20,fill::randu);
mat B(10,20,fill::randu);

some_function( (A+B).eval() );
```

Also note that  the Mat class doesn't have a member function called n_rows(). Instead it has a read-only variable called [n_rows](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#attributes). For example:

```
unsigned int n = X.n_rows;
```

Comment: Ooops. the `( )` was just a silly typo. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

After **Jarod42**'s post, I put some time on this matter and found out another possible solution to this problem, very similar to **Jarod42**'s one. I am replying it as an answer for anyone who might stuck into this same problem like myself.
I just changed the second `as_Mat` function that **Jarod42** has already written.

```
template <typename T>
const Mat<T>& as_Mat(const Mat<T>& m) {return m;}


template<typename T>
Mat<typename T::elem_type> as_Mat(const T& X)
{
    return {X};
}
```

And all user defined functions will contain one line as before.

```
template<typename T>
void some_function(const T & X)
{
    const auto& Y = as_Mat(X);
    // do some stuffs with Y...
    // ....
}
```

This way any delayed evaluation will be converted into matrix, eg. `A+B`, `A*B`, `i*A` (`i` = int, complex<>,double...) etc. etc. etc.

Though I am not sure about the performance of the code and also, as **mtall** mentioned about `.eval()` function, this fix can be very much helpful to build templated libraries using Armadillo, where library users do not need to put `.eval()` every other time. Again, thank you all for your kind help and attention.